# Type erasure in a nested list with a given context bound

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, type-erasure, context-bound

I am going through the book Scala with Cats. I am trying to understand the subtleties of the scala type system. I came up with the following example:

```
object Example extends App {

  sealed trait Serializer[T] {
    def serialize(seq: List[T]): String
  }

  implicit object StringSerializer extends Serializer[String] {
    def serialize(seq: List[String]): String = seq.toString()
  }

  implicit object IntSerializer extends Serializer[Int] {
    def serialize(seq: List[Int]): String =  seq.toString()
  }

  def f1[T0 : Serializer](x: List[List[T0]])(implicit s0: Serializer[T0]): List[String] = {
    x.map(lst => s0.serialize(lst))
  }
  
  // some dummy data
  val col1 = List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
  val col2 = List(12, 200, 80900, 201200, 124420000)
  val col3 = List(121, 12121, 71240000, 44356, 845)
  val data = List(col1, col2, col3)
  
  f1(data)
}
```

Now this does not compile, the following error comes up:

> could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type
> Example.Serializer[Any]

Now I understand why this happens; it is due to my function f1. Because I have a List[Int] and List[String] passed in to the function, the common parent type is Any. So the Type info gets erased, which passes into serializer.

However, given I have put a context bound, shouldn't the compiler first look for the implicit definitons before this takes place? Clearly it does not so my understanding is incorrect. What is the Scala way of getting round this problem.

Any explanations will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the inferred type of `data` is `List[List[Any]]`, so that when you call `f1`, the type that's inferred for `T0` is `Any`, which doesn't have a `Serializer` instance. Even if you don't define `data` as a val, and instead write something like `f1(List(col1, col2, col3))`, the inferred type of `T0` will still be `Any`.

Scala just doesn't really provide any way that you can do the kind of thing you're aiming for. The closest solution is probably something like the magnet pattern—for example you could add something like this:

```
trait SerializableList {
  type T
  def values: List[T]
  def instance: Serializer[T]
  final def apply(): String = instance.serialize(values)
}

object SerializableList {
  implicit def fromSerializer[T0](ts: List[T0])
    (implicit T: Serializer[T0]): SerializableList =
      new SerializableList {
        type T = T0
        val values = ts
        val instance = T
      }
}
```

And then define `f1` like this:

```
def f1(x: List[SerializableList]): List[String] = {
  x.map(_())
}
```

And this actually works for your case, provided that you pass an expression where the element types haven't been inferred yet:

```
scala> f1(List(col1, col2, col3))
res3: List[String] = List(List(a, b, c, d, e), List(12, 200, 80900, 201200, 124420000), List(121, 12121, 71240000, 44356, 845))
```

But if you try `f1(data)` it still won't work, since the static type of `data` is already `List[List[Any]]`:

```
scala> f1(data)
          ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : List[List[Any]]
        required: List[SerializableList]
```

In my view it isn't really a good idea to use implicit conversions like this, anyway, though, even if they're powered by a type class.

As a footnote, what you're seeing doesn't really have anything to do with *type erasure*, which in Scala and Java is about losing access to generic types in runtime reflection. For example, this is an example of how type erasure can enable unsafe programs in Scala:

```
def broken() = List(1, 2, 3) match { case xs: List[String] => xs.head }
```

This compiles (with a warning), but crashes with a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

It's at least arguable that type erasure is a good thing, since unerased types undermine parametricity, and that the only problem in Scala is that its type erasure isn't more complete. The only issue with `broken`, in this view, is the ability to match on runtime type at all—not the fact that it doesn't work for generic types.

In your case there's no runtime reflection, and the fact that you've lost specific type information when `Any` is inferred isn't *erasure*, at least in the sense that term is typically used in this context. Instead it's a matter of the *least upper bound* being taken.