# Ambiguous Implicit Values for Case Class Option Parameter

Tags: scala, types, option-type, typeclass

I am going through some exercises I have invented on case classes and typeclasses. One of the problems I have faced is the following:

```
object Example extends App {

  sealed trait Serializer[T] {
    def serialize(seq: List[T]): String
  }

  implicit object StringSerializer extends Serializer[String] {
    def serialize(seq: List[String]): String = seq.toString()
  }

  implicit object IntSerializer extends Serializer[Int] {
    def serialize(seq: List[Int]): String = seq.toString()
  }

  case class Marker[T: Serializer](lst: Option[List[T]] = None)
  
  Marker() // ambiguous implicit values: here...
}
```

Now this gives an error about ambiguous implicit values. I think this is related to a question I have asked before (albeit a different error message):

[Type erasure in a nested list with a given context bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62501668/type-erasure-in-a-nested-list-with-a-given-context-bound)

Am I correct in that it is the same process at work here, even though the error message is different?

Comment: What do you want your Marker instance to be for, Int or List?

Comment: I was hoping that marker could be either Int or List, and only when a user passes in a list would the type be set. In my mind I assumed the compiler would just not bother when the option was equal to None.

Comment: Well, the `lst` field is not mutable, so there was no way anyone could pass a different list in later

Answer (score 5):

Compiler can't infer `T`. Try to specify `T` explicitly

```
Marker[String]() // compiles
Marker[Int]() // compiles
```

When you provide `lst` it can infer `T` itself

```
Marker(Some(List(1, 2)))
Marker(Some(List("a", "b")))
```

For the same reason

```
Marker(Option.empty[List[Int]])
Marker(Option.empty[List[String]])
Marker[Int](None)
Marker[String](None)
Marker(None: Option[List[Int]])
Marker(None: Option[List[String]])
```

compile while `Marker(None)` doesn't.

Alternatively you can prioritize your implicits

```
trait LowPrioritySerializer {
  implicit object StringSerializer extends Serializer[String] {
    def serialize(seq: List[String]): String = seq.toString()
  }
}

object Serializer extends LowPrioritySerializer {
  implicit object IntSerializer extends Serializer[Int] {
    def serialize(seq: List[Int]): String = seq.toString()
  }
}
```

Then `IntSerializer` will be tried firstly and `StringSerializer` will be tried secondly if `IntSerializer` didn't work (if type is different).

Comment: aha I see now. Thanks!!